# Not sending in Welcome Message in Discord (using discord.py)

Tags: discord.py, python-3.8

I am new to Python as well as StackOver flow. I am coding a Discord Bot for my Guild. I first feature I want to add was sending a Welcome Message in a Specific Channel. I coded it and when running I got no error...but when someone is joining my Server, no message was send by the bot.

Here's my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
TOKEN = '<Bot Token>'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print("Succesfully logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_memeber_join(member):
try:
    channel = bot.get_channel(<Channel ID>)
    await channel.message.send(
        'Welcome to PRIME CLUB {0.mention}'.format(member))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Please Help me in correcting my Mistakes...
Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `on_member_join` to work, you need to enable the `Members Intent`, both in your code and on your bot's dashboard. Info on how to do that is in the [API Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Also, you spelled `member` wrong ("memeber"). Your indentation looks wrong as well (1 tab when going inside of a function).

```py
# Enable intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Fix indentation
    print(...)

# Spell the name of the event correctly
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # Fix indentation
    try:
        channel = ...
```

Comment: Hmm...Do I have to do anything with the scopes....cause it didn't work....I have used only the Bot scope

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything else. Are you sure you did everything I said? Enabling intents both in code & on your dashboard and changing the function's name?

Answer (score 0):

Thx @stijndcl for the help....
Currently This script is working well for me..

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.guild.channels:
        if str(channel.id) == '<CHANNEL ID>':
            await channel.send(f'Welcome!! {member.mention}')
```